# Angular Locked username and password inputs after user logout

Tags: angular, typescript, input, binding

After page refresh Username and Password inputs are working fine, but when you're logging in and then logout these inputs locks. It works but no cursor or text marking is showing.[image: Picture attach]. Only development mode is working fine with no bugs, stage and production have it. I have tested a lot of things, autocomplete, checked inputs events in console through JSON... I suspect:
`<!--bindings={ "ng-reflect-ng-if: "false" }-->`
It can be the problem? How to fix it?

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it clear in order to understand what's your issue exactly? What do you mean with locked exactly? Are they not editable? Also would be helpful if you add some part of your code.

Comment: @k.vincent I found a solution. Locked means: not editable, pressing and nothing happens. Sorry for not putting here code. Problem was with rendering. I created *ngIf with setTimeout and put there all login table. Now the information is loaded separately and everything works fine.

Comment: Glad that it has been solved. Great.